# How to keep focus on TextField but not display keyboard in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, textfield, autofocus

I am new to Flutter. The thing I want is to keep focus on TextField, but not display keyboard. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

To give focus to a text field as soon as it’s visible, use the autofocus property.

```
content_copy
TextField(
  autofocus: true,
);


_dismissKeyboard(BuildContext context) {
   FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return new GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
    this._dismissKeyboard(context);
    },
    child: new Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[/*...*/],
    ),
    ),
 );
}
```

Both of these components should be used together to implement what you are trying to acheive.

Comment: with autofocus, keyboard is being displayed automatically, but I don't want it to be displayed. I can't quite get your approach, could you please provide full example? 
your _dismissKeyboard() method is just losing focus from textfield, isn't it?